# Shaking/Vibration in steering wheel & vehicle

Tags: audi, vibration, shaking, a4

I drive a 2006 Audi A4 Quattro 2.0L Turbo vehicle. I bought off a private seller about 8 months ago. The shaking started randomly about 3 months ago. At first, the shaking was only felt in the steering wheel when I would reach speeds between 50MPH & 60MPH and then would clear out. Over time the problem has become noticeable in the vehicle itself. I started by purchasing brand new wheels and tires all the way around the car. That did not resolve the issue. I then had the tires re-balanced. That also did not resolve my issue. I had the car aligned, that also has not resolved my issue. During the alignment I asked the tech to take a look around to see if he could see anything wrong with the suspension that may be causing the shaking, and he said he did not see anything that stood out. Went back and had the tire shop I purchased the tires from and had them rebalance and rotate the tires and that still did not resolve my shaking issue. Vibration can be felt through the vehicle at higher speeds up to 80MPH now. Any one have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Get the bearings checked and a thorough check of **all** the suspension joints - not much play is needed to cause issues.

Comment: Thanks Solar Mike. Looks like we have a blown out boot on the drivers side outer tie rod. We’re going to start there. Update when install is complete.

Comment: @KristinaMartines, I was going to suggest looking at tie rods and the steering system itself. My bad rack & pinion steering, with some wore out tie rod ends, are causing my '08 Impala to have some shaking at about the same speeds you are talking about. It's surprising the alignment tech didn't notice your boot issue, since that's when my issues were found out after getting my own tires replaced.